# Нет доступа к Spring boot контроллеру, но index.html открывается

Tags: java, spring, сервер, spring-boot, kotlin

У меня есть Spring boot проект, который я задеплоил на удаленный Tomcat сервер. При попытке обратиться к контроллеру, выдает ошибку

> Description: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Но, при обращении к `index.html`, в ответ получаю страницу. Не могу понять, почему доступ к странице есть, а к контроллеру нет, хотя на локальном сервере все работает как задумано.

Структура проекта:

[image: Структура проекта]

Есть какие-то идеи?

### UPD

Запись в файле `catalina.out`:

> SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-19] org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXmlParser.parseWebXml Parse error in application web.xml file at [file:/opt/tomcat/webapps/proxynator/WEB-INF/web.

Идет отсылка к файлу `web.xml`, но у меня его нет.

Comment: по идее если у вас нет web.xml то должен быть класс с конфигурацией,  не точно но возможно наследник WebApplicationContext. Если и java конфигурации нет, то надо её создать иначе как tomcat узнает о ваших маппингах?

Comment: Какая версия *tomcat* используется? Учтите, что согласно [официальной документации](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) без *web.xml* можно обойтись только начиная с версии 7.0.

Comment: Версия Кота 8.5.24
Класса с конфигурацией нет

Comment: Дело в том, что на локальном сервере все отлично работает, только заливаю на удаленный, доступ только к индекс страничке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена. Нужно было всего добавить наследование SpringBootServletInitializer и переопределить метод configure:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
open class Application: SpringBootServletInitializer(){

    @Override
    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder?): 
                           SpringApplicationBuilder {
        return super.configure(application)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```